# Meteor session set/get forcing html to re-render

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a page running with Meteor.js only running on the client. I'm using [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) for setting up the page URL. I have this in the ***before*** section to set a session variable:

```
    before: function () {
        Session.set('employee-number', 0);
}
```

The html has a section with a text box

```
<div class="row-fluid employee-gift-main">
    <div class="span4">
        <label>
            <span># Employees</span>
            <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="employee-text" class="employee-gift input-block-level" id="employee" placeholder="xx"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the js file has a keypress event:

```
'keyup .employee-gift': function(event, template) {
     if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode != 27 && event.keyCode != 13 && event.keyCode != 10 && event.keyCode != 8)) {
         $("#employee").val($("#employee").val().substring(0,$("#employee").val().length - 1));
    }
    else if (event.keyCode >= 48 || event.keyCode <= 57) {
        Session.set('employee-number',$("#employee").val());
    }
}
```

Now, when I set the session variable, it changes some values on some pricing like calculating fees and taxes:

```
sponsorFeeTotal: function() {
    var adminFee = 0;
    if(Session.get('firstTime'))
        adminFee = 45*0.13;

    if( Session.get('employee-number') == '')
        return (Session.get('sponsorFee')+adminFee+parseFloat(Session.get('getTax'))).toFixed(2);
    else    
        return (Session.get('sponsorFee')+parseInt(Session.get('employee-number'))*20*0.13+parseInt(Session.get('employee-number'))*20+adminFee+parseFloat(Session.get('getTax'))).toFixed(2);
},

geTax :function() {
    var adminFee = 0;
    if(Session.get('firstTime'))
        adminFee = 45*0.13;
    if( Session.get('employee-number') == '')
        return (Session.get('getTax')+adminFee).toFixed(2);
    else
        return (Session.get('getTax')+adminFee+parseInt(Session.get('employee-number'))*20*0.13).toFixed(2);
},

employeeNumber: function() {
    return parseInt(Session.get('employee-number'));
},
employeeNumberValue: function() {
    return parseInt(Session.get('employee-number'))*20;
}
```

The get methods then force all the text inputs including the #employee field to be re-loaded. I understand that meteor UI automatically re-renders the parts that depend on a specific key (employee-number) if that key changes. However, this code was working fine with a previous version of meteor. Has the behaviour changed recently and how do I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input#employee is not going to be re-rendered by changing Session.get('employee-number') because it does not depend on that or any other Session value. My guess is that you were previously relying on something higher up the DOM triggering a re-rendering of the entire template when Session.get('employee-number') changed.

That is a major change in Meteor 0.8+ - a change in a reactive data source will not automatically trigger re-rendering of an entire template, but only those specific elements that depend on the data source. So input#employee is not being re-rendered.

I would [read here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) for more information on this change.

Also, as a side note, Iron Router's 'before' hook is being deprecated in favor of 'onBeforeAction'. This is likely not the source of your question because 'before' will be supported through Meteor 1.0 ([see here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/History.md)). Just wanted to point it out for future-proofing.

Comment: You were right. It was an issue with something higher up the DOM. However, I upgraded Meteor to the latest versions and fixed a lot of the things that were breaking. That seemed to have fixed the problem with the DOM as things are working smoothly again.